# filepicker.io -- easy implementation

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I have a site, [btstats.com](http://btstats.com), that provides the following service:

*"It imports a JSON file from 'Bluescan 4.0 Scanner for Android' and generates graphs and stats".*

I implemented Dropbox Chooser on my site with this simple and elegant code to provide the functionality, provided by Dropbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('dropbox-bt').onclick = function()
{
    Dropbox.choose
    ({
    linkType: 'direct',
    extensions: ['.json'],
    multiselect: false,
    success: function (files)
    {
        var dbSelected = "File selected: ";
        var filenamePanel = document.getElementById('filenamePanel');
        filenamePanel.textContent = dbSelected + files[0].name;

        var postLink = files[0].link;
        document.getElementById('postLink').value = postLink;

        var postName = files[0].name;
        document.getElementById('postName').value = postName;   
    }
  });
};
</script>
```

What I like about the code above is that it is small and provides me the file link and file name.

I'm thinking about implementing [filepicker.io](http://filepicker.io), so I can provide to users more cloud storage options.

I couldn't find an easy way to add filepicker.io's window to my site that offers these options. First, I would like to implement it using a button, and I can't find on their documentation an example with `getElementById`.

Would it be possible for someone to guide me or write a small filepicker.io example based on my Dropbox implementation that provides the file link and file name? I'm not a Javascript expert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filepicker code is quite similar:

```
filepicker.setKey('yourApikey');

document.getElementById('filepickerBtn').onclick = selectFile;

function selectFile(){
    filepicker.pick(
        // picker options
        {
            extension: '.json',
        },
        onSuccessCallback
    );
};

function onSuccessCallback(Blob){
    document.getElementById('postName').textContent = Blob.filename;
    document.getElementById('postlink').textContent = Blob.url;
    document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(Blob);            
};
```

Sample html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Filepicker example</h3>
    <p>
        <button id="filepickerBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
            Select json file
        </button>
    </p>
    <p>Filename: <span id="postName"></span></p>
    <p>Filelink: <span id="postlink"></span></p>
    <p>Results: <pre id="results">Upload file to see results</pre></p>
</div>
```

And working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krystiangw/61861wsv/)

Comment: One question: How do I send the value of `<span id="postName">` to --> `<input type="hidden" name="postName" id="postName">`? The way it is now, the value of the `input` is null, but on the Dropbox example listed above, the `input` value is equal to the `<span id>` value.

Comment: There is no inputs in my example but you can simply add it and then assign value the same way. File name is available under 'Blob.filename'. Example: document.getElementById('yourInputID').value = Blob.filename;